# Hibernate with Access 2007

Tags: hibernate, ms-access

This is a tough one.. I started learning Java EE recently and came across this problem - when i run the Hibernate Reverse Engineering Wizard from NetBeans, it says, that it is connecting to the database, then checking the schema, but after that, there are no available tables in the dialog - it is empty, but no error messages.

After googling, I checked a 3rd party driver/dialect from HXTT, it gave no results too, I even tried the Microsoft SQL Server dialect and driver, with an error in hibernate.cfg.

The configuration looks like this:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:/Path is correct</property>
```

The path is correct, I can do every possible thing with JDBC, I doubt there are security restrictions. After the wizard completes, the reveng.xml file has only this line:

```
<schema-selection match-catalog="Path to DB"/>
```

If there really isn't hope for Access + Hibernate, I would love to know a possibility of using it anyway in a web app, for example with JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Access 2007 doesn't seem to be supported. Check [this](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SupportedDatabases) page for compatibility.

Comment: You mean "`ACE` is not supported".

Answer (score 0):

I was struck with this issue for 3 days and now, found the reason why this could occur.

**Step 1**

In Netbeans IDE, Click on Window - Services. Now choose the database connection you created and click "Connect".

*To validate if this connection is good.*

Right click on the connection name and click on Execute Command. Now, wite a simple select query on any table in database. It should give proper results.

If you face error here, delete the connection. Create a new Driver name based on the database driver file and create a new connection to the database.

Remember that, SQL Server default port is 1433.

***Important- The default scheme you select while creating this connection should be "DBO"***

**Step 2**

In your application, add the hibernate.cfg file using the netbeans wizard (Others - Hibernate.cfg) file

Once config file is added, add the reverse engineering wizard by selecting the appropriate config file.

You will be seeing the list of available tables.